# Is there a way to use Angular 2 on jsfiddle or plunker without systemjs?

Tags: angular, webpack, jsfiddle, systemjs

I have been exploring for a minimal Angular2 implementation on plunker or JsFiddle to use when exposing specific features either with other team members or on blog posts.

So far I come to the understanding that the simplest possible solution is using systemjs and some not so good looking imports like so: 
https://embed.plnkr.co/CuY3EyDKsNRJIdpRrQqo/

It would be preferable to use webpack since it's an overall preferred bundler or no bundler and keeping it simple.
But I'll have to stick with the systemjs approach, correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webpackbin](http://www.webpackbin.com/) to have plunker-like project bundled with webpack.

Comment: It looks incredibly promising, wish it would have better/explained embedding options and not be in beta

Comment: Just talked with the author and he's partnering with webpack to get this to the next level, yay
https://twitter.com/christianalfoni/status/823584439720624128